How do I invoke a dialog from a button on a menu rather than in the component itself?
I'm using Vuetify 3 and Vue 3. I have just learned to use some of the techniques in the Vuetify documentation to invoke a dialog that is its own component, separate from the parent component, via a button with an id in the parent. If the button is directly on the parent component, this works fine. However, I want the app that I'm writing to invoke the dialog from a button on a menu and that does NOT work. I don't see why using a button on a menu would cause an issue.
I've put together a Vuetify playground to illustrate the problem.
To see the problem, do the following:

Scroll to the bottom of the page and click on Target Activator 1. A dialog called Target-activated Dialog 1 will appear. It is persistent and can be closed by clicking on either of the buttons on the dialog.
Scroll to the top of the page and click on Examples. A menu showing Target Activator 3 and Target Activator 4 will appear. Click on either of the menu options and NOTHING HAPPENS. What SHOULD happen is that Target Activator 3 displays a dialog that is persistent and can be closed by clicking either of the dialog's buttons. Ditto for Target Activator 4.

I imitated everything from Target Activator 1 in making the Target Activator 3 and 4 buttons (and their corresponding dialogs) but the activator buttons in the menu simply don't work. I'm puzzled about why. Is there some reason that a button in a menu behaves differently from a button directly on the component? That seems very unlikely. It seems much more probable that I've done something foolish but I simply don't see any significant difference between the activator buttons on the menu and the ones at the end of the page. What can I try next?

VMenu is rendered in the DOM outside the normal scope of <div id="app">.  The Target Activator components need to be included somewhere within <v-menu> to work.

@yoduh - Fantastic, you found the problem! I was completely baffled by why this wasn't working. Thank you very much for the explanation and the solution!!
